# Sending AsyncTask through bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I want to send an AsyncTask through a bundle to start another fragment with it.

Therefore I created another class which implements serializable and stores my AsyncTask. I want to put this class into a bundle and start another fragment with it.

```
public class SerializableTask implements Serializable {

    private AsyncTask task;

public SerializableTask(AsyncTask task) {
    this.task = task;
}

    public AsyncTask getTask() { return this.task; }
}
```

Does this work or do I need to overwrite the writeObject or readobject method?

Comment: What you mean by sending asyncTask? Do you want to send a task to another fragment to be executed?

Comment: Yes exactly. Fragment A for example creates the task and serializes it with my class and starts Fragment B with the bundle which holds my class and the task. Then B runs the task

Comment: And why don't you create the task and run in fragment B? if you can communicate the fragments it's better solution I think. Just send the data needed to Fragment B while start.

Comment: Besides, in Android it's better to use Parcelable instead of Serializable due to the speed of the first one.

Comment: But it should be a generic fragment. I think it will be hardly possible to send generic objects to a fragment. Besides that if I manage to send the attributes to Fragment B, since it should be generic there wouldn't be a way in Java to tell what the post execute method of the asynctask should do, right?

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are using is not right. Just send data via bundle not task, then recreate the task with the same data. The bundle is used to pass only data. If needed you can send state of your task in form of data and on achieve you can restart the task with the same state.

Comment: but how can I recreate the "doInBackground", "onProgressUpdate" and "onPostExecute" methods?

Comment: just create new task with old data

Comment: I think I miss something..If I have multiple AsyncTasks in my Project and Frag A creates one of these and gives the data to Fragment B, how can Fragment B know which task to recreate since I could send first AsyncTaskA and after a while I could send AsyncTaskB (which are both created by some other fragment and should be both executed in FragmentB)